# When writing ranges, must the start and the end of the range be both written out as words or both written in numerals?

Tags: numbers, style-manuals, range-inclusion

Usually, numbers 0-10 are written out as words. What should be used when a range starts below ten but ends above it? Is the word "to" used, or a hyphen?

E.g.,

> 9-25

, or

> nine to twenty-five

, or

> nine to 25

, or

> nine - 25

I think that, besides `9-25` and `nine to twenty-five`, the other options seem unnatural. What do the style guides say? There are also consistency rules. How do we choose between all numbers and all written out words?

This question relates to [Spelling out number ranges?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569216/spelling-out-number-ranges), but this specific case wasn't addressed.

Example of a "mixed range": https://www.theguardian.com/money/2023/oct/23/bookingcom-customers-targeted-by-scam-confirmation-emails.

Comment: `9-25 = -16` :) You've missed out one option though: "9 to 25" which IMO is the most readable. The style guides will advise on consistency, so don't mix the styles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which format is best for a number range?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362220/which-format-is-best-for-a-number-range) CMoS gives the example << 38–45 >>, but << thirty to forty >> etc is common for 'simpler' numbers. // Don't mix numerals and words: this trumps the 'write one to ten in words, thereafter use numerals' recommendation.

Comment: The style depends on the context.

Comment: There are en dashes and em dashes: yours is right but the spacing was wrong; pp. 9-25. The em dash is wrong here.